# CSS link pseudo class does not get applied

Tags: css, pseudo-class

This is my HTML

```
<ul class="anchor">
    <li><a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="test">Item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item3</a></li>
</ul>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
/* Anchor tags */
.anchor {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.anchor a:link {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

I do not really understand what happens there. The red color is only applied to the second link, but not to the first. I understand that it is not applied to the third one, since the href tag is empty.

Can someone explain me the differences and how to fix it, so that my first link also gets colored in red?

Comment: `:link` only targets the unvisited links: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:link . Just remove the `:link` and it should be fine

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN's Web Docs

> The `:link CSS` pseudo-class represents an element that has not yet
> been visited. It matches every unvisited `<a>` or `<area>` element
> that has an href attribute.

Meaning you must have visited the first link

If you want to style all links red you must simply change the selector from `.anchor a:link` to `.anchor a` or `.anchor a:any-link`

Comment: Ok so my browser tracks website to archieve that? When change google to blabla it works. I thought it is only applied in the current session

Comment: The browser checks the history and styles them accordingly. You need to clear the browser history in order to reset the link state

Comment: Yes the browser checks the history. I updated my answer to better fit your question.